# How to get "File" in PFUser through using column Pointer to PFUser?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Now, I am making message apps, now.
Below picture is showing about last_message class.
It include main column 
  
-sender
  
-receiver
  
-graphicFile

[image]

Then, I could show image in above image through setting image into graphicFile column directly.

But it's so redundant because they have to update graphicFile when they messages. I think using pointer is better, but I am not sure how to use point to PFUser that has User's profileImage.

Which is better to be in present code or using pointer ?
And If using pointer is better, how use pointer ?

I show my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object     {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 commentTableViewCell *cell = (commentTableViewCell *)[tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[commentTableViewCell alloc] init];
 }

     cell.usernameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"receiver"];
     cell.commentLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"message"];
     cell.leftImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"graphicFile"];
     [cell.leftImage loadInBackground];

     return cell;
 }
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you are asking exactly. What is your `graphicImage`? Is it the user's profile picture or a sent image?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, graphicImage is about User's profile picture. There is PFUser's column. I want to use it in last_message class.

Comment: Then why are you saving the profile picture (graphicImage) in the `object`? Why not saving the profile picture in the user object and accessing it through the user?

Comment: I can understand how to call graphicImage in PFUser like this code. PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];    [query whereKey:@"foo" equalTo:@"bar"];              But I think when I make a cell from last_message class's record, it's redundant. Calling PFQuery many times equal to cell's number is so difficult. I think it's over parse's free user constraint about 30 request/ 1 second .